# momentjs custom calendar output with reusing moment values

Tags: javascript, calendar, momentjs

In UI there is a place where we want to have localised string:

- if the date is in same day: "Today, 02/06/2018"
- if it is in next day: "Tomorrow, 02/07/2018"
- if it is in next week: "Monday, 02/12/2018"
- if it is later: "In 10 days, 02/16/2018"

so for example for french locale it will be:

- if the date is in same day: "Aujourd'hui, 06/02/2018"
- if it is in next day: "Demain, 07/02/2018"
- if it is in next week: "Lundi, 12/02/2018"
- if it is later: "En 10 jours, 16/02/2018"

How can achieve this with moment.js? Please provide me code, not docs link, I have read docs and it did not helped.

I have expected this would work for first case:

`moment().calendar( null, {
            sameDay : '[Today], L',
        });`

But "Today" is not getting localized. It is "Today" for german too, and it should be "Heute". Because I was thinking "Today" is keyword replacing by momentjs for correct localized value. But in real it is just literal string.

**EDIT 04/06/2018 (added code example)**

```js
moment.locale('de');
var result = moment().calendar();
var result2 = moment().calendar( null, {
  sameDay : '[Today], L',
});
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = result2;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/locale/de.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8x4on1nf/11/

Many thanks

Comment: Have you read Changing locale [globally](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) and [locally](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/)? Can you share a snippet showing the issue? Make sure you imported each required.

Comment: @VincenzoC I have added code, thanks :)

Comment: I ended up with regex replacement for time (date in your case)

Comment: @elmeister not exactly the answer I was looking for, but you give me good idea.. I will dynamically create custom calendar "onLangChanged" event :)

Comment: Something like that in my case `const messageCalendar = message.sent_on.calendar(); const result = timeRegex.test(messageCalendar) ? messageCalendar.replace(timeRegex, message.sent_on.format(settings.timeFormat)) : messageCalendar`